# On one version of chrome a picture stretches vertically

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, chromium

On http://phoenixprints.org/viewpicture.php?pid=258 the main picture stretches vertically and looks bad. I don't know why its happening at all, and seems to only happen sometime. This does not happen on all pictures, and is puzzling me.

I'm running 18.0.1025.151 (Developer Build 130497 Linux) Built on Ubuntu 12.04 on chromium and it does not happen.

19.0.1084.56 m google chrome on windows xp it does?

Answer (score 2):

You set the image height to 100% with this style:

```
.viewimg img {
  width:  100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

None of the parent elements seemed to have an explicit `height` given, so WebKit (Mac/Safari in my case) probably chose the window's height as a reference for calculating percentages.

In firefox it only works because it seems to completely ignore the `height: 100%` part. Try it with some other values, and you will see.

My solution would be simply removing the `height: 100%` from the css, browsers should (in theory) resize the image by keeping its normal aspect ratio.